# How to implement my own upload file component and make it customizable in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, components, frontend, solid-principles

I'm working on a project which expects a lot of places where I have to implement upload file component with different styles. I want to create highly customizable component which design I can modify easily and also I don't want to repeat myself and want to extract all the common logic into one place.

At this moment I have a vue.js version 2.2.2 and bulma css framework. I have a basic implementation of this component with only one design available. It supports a few states which represents current upload status:

1. component is waiting for the input
2. upload started
3. upload finished successfully
4. upload failed

Also this component is responsible for the upload process.

At this my component has a lot of responsibilities:
1. it knows how to deal with statuses:

```
<p v-if="isWaiting">
...
</p>

<div v-if="isLoading" class="is-loading">
    <p class="title">{{currentPercent}} %</p>
</div>

...
```

```
data() { return {
    currentStatus = Statuses.waiting
}}

computed: {
    isWaiting() {
      return this.currentStatus === Statuses.waiting;
    },
    ...
}
```

2. it knows how to upload the data and count the current percent of data which is already transfered:

```
selectedFileChanged: async function(event) {
      if (event.target.files.length === 0) return;

      this.currentStatus = Statuses.uploading;
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", this.selectedFile);

      try {
        const result = (await axios.post("some url", formData, {
          onUploadProgress: progress => {
            const loaded = progress.loaded;
            const total = progress.total;
            this.currentPercent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
          }
        })).data;

        this.currentStatus = Statuses.uploaded;

        this.$emit("fileUploaded", {
          file: this.selectedFile,
          payload: result
        });
      } catch (exception) {
        this.currentStatus = Statuses.error;
      }
    }
```

3. it has only one style which I can use

you can find the full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-gz2gk

So my question is: how to build this component to have an opportunity to change it's style easily and how to deal with upload statuses?

It seems to me that:
1. the component shouldn't know that axios is and how to upload the data;
2. the component should only be responsible for the current status and how to display it

I can introduce a new upload service which will know how to upload the data and add a new prop (current status) for upload file component and change it from the parent component. But in this case I will write the same code for all instances of the component.

Does someone know best practices of how-to create such customizable component?

**UPDATE 1**
I've tried to implement this functionality using slots and ended up with: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pi7e9

The component still knows how to upload the data, but now I can change the style of upload component.
So the new question is: how to work with slots and do not transfer a lot of variables and how to deal with uploading. I don't want my component to know how to upload the data :(

Comment: is it that you want to pass a e.g. `changed` prop containing the logic?

Comment: I've ended up with the following:
So far the component should be independent I will not extract the upload logic. Instead of this I will change the axios library and will use the default XMLHttpRequest API. It will give me all the stuff I want and my component will manage its state by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finished the component in the followig way:

In my parent component I have two different styles for my component:

```html
  <div id="app" class="container box">
    <upload-file url="url"></upload-file> <-- the default one with statuses outside -->

    <upload-file url="url"> <-- custom one which look like a box with statuses in it -->
      <template #fileselect="{status, change}">
        <custom-file-upload :status="status" @change="change"></custom-file-upload>
      </template> <-- I've used custom-file-upload component here and tnjected all the properties from default implementation -->
    </upload-file>
  </div>
```

My default file input is nothing but a slot with default implementation:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="fileselect" :change="selectedFileChanged" :status="status">
      <input id="fileselect" @change="selectedFileChanged" class="file-input" type="file">

      <div class="help is-info" v-if="isWaiting">Waiting</div>
      <div class="help is-success" v-if="isUploaded">Uploaded</div>
      <div class="help is-info" v-if="isUploading">Uploading {{currentPercent}} %</div>
      <div class="help is-error" v-if="isFailed">Failed</div>
    </slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

and what is the code looks like:

```js
  name: "upload-file",

  props: ["url"], // url which will be used in upload request

  data() {
    return {
      currentStatus: 1,
      selectedFile: null,
      currentPercent: 0
    };
  },

computed: {
    someOtherProperties,
    status() {
      return {
        isWaiting: this.isWaiting, // this.currentStatus === 1
        isUploaded: this.isUploaded,
        isUploading: this.isUploading,
        isFailed: this.isFailed,

        currentPercent: this.currentPercent,
        selectedFile: this.selectedFile
      };
    }
  },

 methods: {
    selectedFileChanged: function(event) {
      this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // some handlers for XHR

      xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);

      xhr.send(formData);
    }
  }
```

Now I can use the file upload component with different styling but it will encapsulate in a base implementation all the status handling and upload logic.

I hope this solution will help someone :)

To view the full version of the code, please follow https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pi7e9